# Execute bash script in linux kernel

Tags: linux, bash, module, kernel, system-calls

I have read many  so questions and answers about this topic but I still don't have any idea why my program doesn't work.

My script:

a.c

```
   #include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
   #include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
   #include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
   #include<linux/kmod.h>

   static int __init hello_start(void)
   {
       printk(KERN_INFO "Loading rooted module...\n");
       char* argv[] = {"/home/tomasz/", "s.sh", NULL};

       static char* envp[] = { "HOME=/",  "TERM=linux",   "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL };
       call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
       return 0;
   }

   static void __exit hello_end(void)
   {
       printk(KERN_INFO "exit.\n");
   }

   module_init(hello_start);
   module_exit(hello_end);
```

/home/tomasz/s.sh

```
#for example
reboot
# but in the future here will be sending file by ftp
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't script run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/bin/bash` as the executable and your script as the first argument:

```
char* argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "/home/tomasz/s.sh", NULL};
```